# storing the json values to li using data() using handlebar js

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I have a json structure is like this..

```
{
"event": [
    {
        "ids": [
            "100",
            "101"
        ],
        "eventlist": [
            {
                "title": "Title1",
                "day": "Fri",
                "date": "2",
                "endDate": "6",
                "month": "1"
            },
            {
                "title": "Title2",
                "day": "Mon",
                "date": "5",
                "endDate": "5",
                "month": "1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

HTML Handlebar template..

```
{{#event}}
  {{#each eventlist}} 
   <li>
      <div>{{title}}</div>
      <div>{{day}}</div>
      <div>{{month}}</div>
   </li>
   {{/each}}
{{/event}}
```

How can i store the values title,day,month as a jquery.data() value into the li , so that i can access the data of li using li.data()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add them as data attributes:

```
<li data-title="{{title}}" data-day="{{day}}" data-month="{{month}}">
```

jQuery will be able to access them through `.data()`:

```
var title = $('li').data('title');
```